# Identify the default workflow user

Tags: apex, workflow, query

How can one identify the default workflow user in Salesforce? Or even check if it is set? Is it possible to query for it?

I know I can check using the UI. I need to identify it in apex.

Comment: You can check it via UI. Here is a nice article from Salesforce https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_defaultuser.htm&language=en_US

Comment: I forgot to mention that I need to check this using code, not browsing in the UI. Edited my question.. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible through SOQL (API or other means).